# how to display an object in one row of smart table

Tags: angular, ng2-smart-table

[image: entity from MongoDB]
[image]

I want to display those 3 attributes "`currencyCode`, `Amount`, `serialData`" in one case of table.

I'm using ng2-smart-table with angular 11
and I'm try this code but nothings work

```js
      dateTime: {
        title: 'Date & Time',
      },
      montant: {
        title: 'Montant',
      },      
      serialNbr: {
        title: 'serialNbr',
          CurrencyCode: {
            valuePrepareFunction: (row) => { return row.serialNbr.CurrencyCode }
          },
          Amount: {
            valuePrepareFunction: (row) => { return row.serialNbr.Amount }
          },
          SerialData: {
            valuePrepareFunction: (row) => { return row.serialNbr.SerialData }

          },
      },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fix my issue perfectly and i share this code to help anyone else have the same problem, if you have a nested field or a field that is an array of objects
[image]

```js
dateTime: {
        title: 'Date & Time',
      },
      montant: {
        title: 'Montant',
      },      
      serialNbr: {
        title: 'Serial Number',
        valuePrepareFunction: (serialNbr) => {
          return serialNbr.map(s => "" + s.CurrencyCode + ","+s.Amount+","+s.SerialData+" ").toString()
        }  
      },
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation

> valuePrepareFunction  - function run against a value before it gets inserted into a cell. You can use it to modify how a value is displayed in the cell.
> This function will be invoked with 2 parameters: cell, row
> [Documentation](https://akveo.github.io/ng2-smart-table/#/documentation)

I think you should change your code in the following

```
    serialNbr: {
        title: 'serialNbr',
         valuePrepareFunction: (cell, row) => {
           return `${row.serialNbr.CurrencyCode} ${row.serialNbr.Amount } ${row.serialNbr.SerialData }` 
        },
      },
```

Comment: it didn't work either 
it show me in the row undefiend instead of object 
if you have another suggestion plz tell me

Comment: may be try to log out everything that being passed into `valuePrepareFunction` and share with results. Because I haven't had any experience with that library

Comment: Or try to access those properties on the cell variable `cell.CurrencyCode`

Comment: okay thx
and did you have anther suggestion to display those 3 attributes

Comment: What do you mean another suggestion? You still didn't manage to display those properties?